# Tailwind CSS animations not working in ReactJs/NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I just started learning Tailwind and Nextjs and I was actually coding along a tutorial and did everything exactly as it was in the video. I want to use the bounce animation on an icon when hovered over. The funny thing is that it actually did work the first time but then it just stopped working.

```
function HeaderItem({Icon, title}) {
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center cursor-pointer group w-12 sm:w-20 hover:text-white">
            <Icon className="h-8 mb-1 group-hover:animate-bounce"/>
            <p className="opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100 tracking-widest">{title}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is my tailwind config so far

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  purge: ['./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Group-hover` in animation as it's not enabled by default, so you need `variants` `extend` your config in `tailwind.config.js` check this [Doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#group-hover)

You can also check this code in the `Tailwind Playground` [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/rUnV4orAmb).

```
//tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {},
  variants: {
    extend: {
      animation: ['group-hover'],
    },
  },
}
```

> Notice! now currently `group-hover:animation` is not working on latest tailwind version. check this [doc](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/play.tailwindcss.com/issues/54#issuecomment-868382625)

Happy, coding!

Comment: The OP is using JIT mode, all the variants are enabled by default in it. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#all-variants-are-enabled However the issue you have mentioned is the correct one. I don't understand why the issue creator closed it.

Comment: yes, I checked to use `group-hover`, but it did't  work in JIT mode, so I found it reason to answer this.:) is that issue closed?

Comment: Tried doing the same, still it didn't work. Do you have any other solutions?

Comment: A fix for the issue [was merged](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/pull/5223) a week or two ago, but the creator of Tailwind, Adam, is [on vacation right now](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/4705#issuecomment-899646259). So, the package doesn't have a new version yet. If anyone is really anxious to get their dev env temporarily working, I created an [NPM package with the fix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailwindcss-key-frames-fix), note that you must modify the node_modules folder name and the package.json to be `tailwindcss`, not `tailwindcss-fix-...`